# Create SQL one-to-many relationship with itself

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create a one-to-many relationship on a `table A` with it's own records.

I thought I could just create a second `table B`, with two foreign keys linking to `table A`. It appears that this is not sufficient, as LINQ-to-SQL generated a one-to-one relationship. What am I missing?

Some context: `table A` contains tags, and tags can be sub tags of tags.

Edit: Maybe I need a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide sample data and expected output

Comment: Sounds like you need something like a `ParentID` column.... which, for a sub tag row, is populated with the ID of it's parent tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to make the two keys in your link table B, the primary key of this table.

Also, Linq2SQL seems to generate properties based on the names of your keys. This resulted in some odd names for me.

Answer (score 0):

SQL server won't let you create a foreign key for the table referencing itself with `ON DELETE CASCADE` or `ON UPDATE CASCADE` since it may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. But you can create foreign key with `ON DELETE NO ACTION` and `ON UPDATE NO ACTION`.

```
ALTER TABLE tagtablename ADD FOREIGN KEY ([parent_id]) REFERENCES [tagtablename] ([id]) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table with the following columns  itemid and MasterID
in the column masterid you have the itemid of the item it links to

```
select a.Itemid,b.itemid  from table1 as a inner join table1 as b on a.Itemid=b.MasterID
```

Above query will give you a result like this :

```
a_itemid b_itemid
3020079  3020334
3020079  3020335
3045396  3045397
3045396  3045398
3045396  3045401
3020079  3577149
```